# How to stream and Save video from Raspberry pi using gstreamer

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to stream and save. I am able to see the stream, but the file I save is not opening in VLC even after it is of some size.

Sending command:

`raspivid -t 0 -w 1080 -h 720 -fps 25 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! gdppay ! tcpserversink host=192.168.43.7 port=6002`

Receiving command:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v tcpclientsrc host=192.168.43.7 port=6002 ! gdpdepay ! queue ! rtph264depay ! tee name =t ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false t. ! queue ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4`

None of these are throwing any error, but I am not able to view the saved file.